# Custom form builder not invoked in the fields_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form with 3 related models. I want all the fields to be built by my custom form builder `PanelFormBuilder`. However only the `form_for` seems to be processed by my form builder and the `fields_for` doesn't - it gets processed by the default one. I can't for the life of me work out why.

This works:

```
<%= panel_form_for @firm do |f| %>
```

This doesn't:

```
<%= panel_fields_for @firm.company do |c| %>
```

Here are the custom methods:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def panel_form_for(object, options = {}, &block)
    options[:builder] = PanelFormBuilder
    form_for(object, options, &block)
  end

  def panel_fields_for(object, options = {}, &block)
    options[:builder] = PanelFormBuilder
    fields_for(object, options, &block)
  end
end
```

Here is the custom form builder

```
class PanelFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  delegate :content_tag, :tag, to: :@template

  %w[text_field text_area password_field].each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) do |name, *args|
      options = args.extract_options!
      options.merge!(:class => "required")
      super(name, *(args + [options]))
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my own answer. Turns out I should have been doing this:

```
<%= panel_form_for @firm do |f| %>
```

Followed by:

```
<%= f.fields_for :company do |c| %>
```

I don't need the `panel_fields_for` at all.

Comment: At least with us, this stopped working in Rails 7. Anybody else? Still trying to come up with a solution...

Comment: For those wondering, we ended up having to use just `fields_for` and not `f.fields_for` and then manually specifying the `builder` option. Not sure where this changed exactly but I've created a Github Issue on the Rails repo to document the issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46154

Answer (score 3):

Look at the definition of `fields_for`:

```
fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

When you call `fields_for` with the block as an argument, Ruby will not be able to figure out that the `options` parameter you specify is actually the options, but instead think it is the `record_object` parameter.

You can just pass `nil` as the second parameter, and your custom builder will be instantiated:

```
fields_for(object, nil, options, &block)
```

This can be good to know in situations where you don't have access to the builder object of the form, like when you create some of the fields from a separate `yield` block.